# Toolbar in fragment doesn't display its title

Tags: android, fragment, title

The style of my activity is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".
There is a toolbar in the fragment, which is added to my activity later.

I just cannot set the title of the actionbar. Codes below don't work. Please help me. How to set the title of the toolbar in a fragment?

```
//In the fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        toolbar.setTitle("aaa");
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        CharSequence title = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getTitle();

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Your Activity theme is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" right, and you need a fragment with title which placed in same activity.

Comment: Yes. All the activities in the project use that theme. It works well when toolbar is placed in activity level. While toolbar in a fragment could display the right home icon and it could get the right title which is set in advance, the
problem is the title does not show.

Comment: If you need screen with toolbar and you want to use fragment then you should use the activity with Actionbar theme and you can inflate your fragment in that activity. It should be very convenient.

Comment: To use toolbar, the theme should exclude actionbar, or there might be a conflict.

Comment: I find out where the problem is. I set the height of CollapsingToolbarLayout is the same as the height of Toolbar. Home icon shows but title doesn't. If the height is set to a specific number, say 200dp, then everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

try this add `ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` in your **Activity** and set **Actionbar title** as per your fragment changes try this it will sure help to you

```
        ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            if(position==0){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nilesh Rathod");

                // or try this
                Toolbar actionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
                actionBarToolbar.setTitle("NILESH");
                setSupportActionBar(actionBarToolbar);


            }else if(position==1){
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Prem Rathod");
                // or try this
                Toolbar actionBarToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);            
                actionBarToolbar.setTitle("PREM");
                setSupportActionBar(actionBarToolbar);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: The first didn't work for me. As for the second one, setActionBarTitle() is not a method of AppCompatActivity, is it?

Comment: This is the official demo activity provided by android studio 2.3.3. Core codes:

Comment: yup when you change your view pager page at that time as per view pager position change the action bar title

Comment: Er, The toobar is in fragments, not in Activity. Cannot find R.id.toolbar_actionbar.

Comment: why you are add tool bar in fragment just add in you activity.xml so you can use in all fragment of that activity

Comment: Well. It seems google MVP samples use fragment as VIEW. So most of the UI things are moved from Activity to Fragment in my project. Almost every fragment has a toolbar, so I write a BaseFragment, the parent of all fragments. In order to use float action bar, coordinatorlayout and some shared element animation, I guess it's best to keep toolbar in fragments. Somewhere is not right?  >_<

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



        CharSequence title = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().getTitle();

        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Comment: set title after setting action bar

Answer (score 0):

> Fragment cannot override toolbar from main activity even when you have
>   setHasOptionsMenu(false); So u have to do it true a menu and populate
>   in toolbar u created in your onCreateView of fragment

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu."Menu u created");
    Menu menu = toolbar.getMenu();
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Please add some explanation.